# Error code -1073741511 (0xC0000139) when launching a program made with SFML in Clion

Tags: c++, sfml

This question is a followup to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558533/sfml-reference-error-cmake-clion-windows-and-mingw) where I was having errors when trying to link the libraries.

Now it's all fixed ! It compiles without any problem, up until the point where I try to launch the program. It doesnt do anything, just this comes out of the console :

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Adventures\cmake-build-debug\Adventures.exe
Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)
```

Which sounds weird because i've looked it up and it looks like a dll missing tho I've tried adding the SFML_STATIC define and all the .dll in the .exe folder but still doesnt work...

Any idea ?

Comment: What happens when you start it with the debugger?

Comment: The error codes is then 0, and a black window appears for a slip microsecond @Quentin

Comment: I just switched the version for my SFML from 2.3.2 to 2.4.2 and still the same errors

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code when using the debugger?

Comment: I did It didn't work, i've placed a breakpoint on every single line of code and it doesnt stop, just like if ran in normal mode

Comment: That sounds like a problem during static initialisation (common if you are using any global or static SFML resources, such as texture, image, etc.). Have you checked the SFML example code works?